# .next() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So,

```
if($(this).hasClass('active')){             
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).prev().addClass('active');                  
}
```

works fine, it adds the class "active" to this previous div of the same kind.

```
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).next().addClass('active');
}
```

However, adds the class to the next div (as i intend for it to do) for about 0.5 of a second BUT then removes it.

Here's ALL of the jQuery (as per your comments below) - Please do not comment on my horrible code organization

```
$(window).load(function () {

    // Initial variables
    var numberSlides = 0;
    var currentSlide = 1;
    var ready = true;
    var pageWidthR = $(document).width() - 352;
    var pageWidthL = $(document).width() - 352;

    // Update number of slides by number of .slide elements
    $('#features-slider .slide').each(function () {
        numberSlides++;
    });

    // Go through each slide and move it to the left of the screen
    var i = 0;

    $($('#features-slider .slide').get().reverse()).each(function () {

        if (i == 0) {

        } else {
            var newWidth = i * 115;
            $(this).css('left', '-' + newWidth + '%');
        }

        i++;

    });

    // Animate the first slide in
    $('#features-slider .slide:last-child').addClass('active').animate({
        left: 0
    }, 1500);

    // Remove the loading message
    $('#loading').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $('#loading').remove();

        // Now that we're done - we can show it
        $('#features-slider').show();
    });

    /***** Left and Right buttons *****/

    /* Right */
    $('#rightbutton').click(function () {

        var numberSlides = 0;
        $('#features-slider .slide').each(function () {
            numberSlides++;
        });

        var index = $('.slide.active').index() + 1;

        if (!$('.slide').is(':animated') && index != 1) {

            $('#features-slider .slide').each(function () {


                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

                    var currentLeft = $(this).css('left');
                    var newLeft = parseInt(currentLeft) + 115;

                } else {

                    var currentLeft = $(this).css('left');
                    var newLeft = parseInt(currentLeft) + 115;

                }


                $(this).animate({
                    left: newLeft + '%'
                }, 1500);


                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                    $(this).prev().addClass('active');

                }

            });

        }

    });

    /* Left */
    $('#leftbutton').click(function () {

        var numberSlides = 0;
        $('#features-slider .slide').each(function () {
            numberSlides++;
        });

        var index = $('.slide.active').index() + 1;
        if (!$('.slide').is(':animated') && index != numberSlides) {

            $('#features-slider .slide').each(function () {

                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

                    var currentLeft = $(this).css('left');
                    var newLeft = parseInt(currentLeft) - 115;

                } else {

                    var currentLeft = $(this).css('left');
                    var newLeft = parseInt(currentLeft) - 115;

                }

                $(this).animate({
                    left: newLeft + '%'
                }, 1500);

                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

                    $(this).next().addClass('active');
                    $(this).removeClass('active').not($(this).next());

                }

            });

        }

    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Hide the slider and show a loading message while we do stuff and the images / DOM loads - Also disable overflow on the body so no horizontal scrollbar is shown
    $('body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
    $('#features-slider').hide();
    $('#loading').html('<center> <img id="loader" src="/wp-content/themes/responsive/library/images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading</center>');

});
```

**RESOLVED**

New left button function :

```
                                $('#leftbutton').click(function(){

                var numberSlides = 0;
                $('#features-slider .slide').each(function(){
                    numberSlides++;
                });

                var index = $('.slide.active').index()+1;

                if( !$('.slide').is(':animated') && index != numberSlides  ){

                    var done = false;               

                    $('#features-slider .slide').each(function(){

                        if($(this).hasClass('active')){

                            var currentLeft = $(this).css('left');
                            var newLeft = parseInt(currentLeft)-115;

                        } else {

                            var currentLeft = $(this).css('left');
                            var newLeft = parseInt(currentLeft)-115;

                        }

                    $(this).animate({left: newLeft+'%'}, 1500);

                    if($(this).hasClass('active') && done == false){

                            $(this).next().addClass('active');
                            $(this).removeClass('active');
                            done = true;

                    }

            });

            });
```

Comment: You haven't posted enough of your code for anybody to tell.

Comment: Show us some Javascript.

Comment: Could be anything, calling a new function or setting an interval around the remove function, running the code before you have loaded the whole thing. You need to show more code.

Comment: Where is that code being called from?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://robzu.com/sscce-short-self-contained-correct-compilable-example)

Comment: Updated above. Will make fiddle. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're iterating forward through the elements, then it should be clear what's going on - you add the "active" class to the next element, and then the next iteration takes it away.

This is just a guess however as you did not post enough code for me (or anybody else) to be sure.

*edit* — ok now that you've updated the question, it's clear that the guess was correct.  The `.each()` function will iterate forward through the elements.  When an element has the "active" class, and the code removes it and adds it to the next element, then on the next iteration the work is undone.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referencing `this` and by the behavior you're describing, you are likely iterating a loop for a list of elements.  As a result, you are completing the action you want but the next iteration is removing the previous changes due to your usage of removing a class and then adding the class back.

As it stands now, your code does not illustrate how this occurence can be happening.

**Update:**
As suspected, you seem to be looping as signified by: `each(function(){`.  While iterating through your objects the class is being pushed forward and is not acting as desired.  You are stating add the class to the next element, but remove it from the current element, and this behavior continues through your iteration.

On a side note, update your code to call `removeClass()` on the current object first, before adding it to the next object:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: It'll still remove "active" from the class of the next element on the subsequent iteration.

Comment: Sorry, that instruction was not to aleviate that problem but just a suggestion as the previous structure did not make sense.